# Как в python в классе-потомке добавить пару (ключ - значение) в список класса предка?

Tags: python-3.x, ооп

Как в python в классе-потомке добавить пару (ключ - значение) в список класса-предка?
Например:

```
class A:
    l = {'a': 1}
class B(A):
    # Вот здесь
    l = {'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так:

```
l.update(A.l)
```

В контексте:

```
class A:
    l = {'a': 1}
class B(A):
    l = ({'b': 2})
    l.update(A.l)      # здесь
```

---

Тест:

```
print(B.l)
```

Вывод:

> ```
> {'b': 2, 'a': 1}
> ```